# Обновление информации о cookie

Tags: jquery

Есть кнопка, первый клик по ней выкидывает модальное окно с предложением зарегистрироваться. После submit'а этой формы, куки должно "записаться" и кнопка выполняет свою прежнюю роль (в данном случае - это `label`). Как можно обновить данные о куки без перезагрузки страницы?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if (!$.cookie('hideModal')) {
    $("label").click(function(event) {
    $('.popup-modal-layer').addClass('popup-modal-layer--is-on');
    $('.close--block').click(function() {
    $('.popup-modal-layer').removeClass('popup-modal-layer--is-on')});
    event.preventDefault();
    })  

    }

    $('form').on('submit', function(){
    $.cookie('hideModal', true);
    alert('Message sent!');
    form.submit();
    });
});
```